Get Python child process PID by name
I would like to ask for your help. I can retrieve the python child process, but how do I get the PID from the received data?
ps -ef | grep -i '[p]ython'

I get this:
`XY   8206  8197  0 17:04 ?        00:00:00 [python3] <defunct>
 XY   8207  8197  0 17:04 ?        00:00:00 [python3] <defunct>
 XY   8208  8197  0 17:04 ?        00:00:00 [python3] <defunct>
 XY   8209  8197  0 17:04 ?        00:00:00 [python3] <defunct>
 XY   26941   777  3 16:04 ?        00:02:28 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/thonny
 XY   27262 27110  1 16:06 ?        00:01:15 python3 /home/XY/pisokjo.py

From this I should get the PID of pisokjo.py on the bottom line (27262)
Thanks
I'm trying this, but the syntax is obviously not good:
sudo kill -9 `ps -ef | grep -i '[p]ython pisokjo.py' | awk '{print $1}'`

Not working:
   pid=`ps -ef | grep '[p]ython pisokjo.py' | awk '{ print $1 }'`    echo $pid

It's almost good, but I still get two numbers:

pid=`ps -ef | grep 'python3 /home/XY/pisokjo.py' | awk '{      pos = index($3, "|");     
 print pos; }'`     
  echo $pid


You know there's a pkill command that combines kill and pgrep?

This will vary by operating system. Is thus Linux, Mac, windows or other?

##EDITED##
your fist command :
  pid=`ps -ef | grep '[p]ython pisokjo.py' | awk '{ print $1 }'`    echo $pid

is not extracting porcess id its because your awk '{ print $1 }' is going to extract first field from the porcess list which is corresponding to the user who initaited the process not process id
if you cahnge you command to this :
pid=$(ps -ef | grep '[p]ython3 /home/XY/pisokjo.py' | awk '{print $2}')
echo $pid
**or** 
pid=`ps -ef | grep '[p]ython pisokjo.py' | awk '{ print $2 }'`    echo $pid

it will work as it will be slececting the right field from the column in porcess lists
note
first command is mroe modern way of command subtitution in shell scripting

That's a useless grep. Generally probably don't reinvent pgrep again.

@nabin please never post "try this" or code-only answers on Stack Overflow.  Every answer worth keeping in this repository of knowledge deserves to be accompanied with a plain English explanation.

@mickmackusa i have edited the answer with explanation
